# Clarity on Wikipedia article on Convolutional Neural Network - input volume depth

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm reading the [Wikipedia page for Convolutional Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) along with some other papers and references. In the wiki article under the section called 'Building Blocks', subsection called 'Convolutional layer', there is the first mention of the input volume depth: "The layer's parameters consist of a set of learnable filters (or kernels), which have a small receptive field, but extend through the full depth of the input volume.".

Can someone please explain what is meant by this ? What is the length, breadth and depth of the input volume ? Is the length just the number of pixels in one dimension, the breadth the number of pixels in the other dimension and the volume simply the number of features for the image ?

Comment: do you know what is a convolution in $2d$ ? it is $y(i,j) = \sum_{n,k} h(i-n,j-k) x(n,k)$ where $x$ is the input (2d) array, $y$ is the output array, and $h$ the filter, that usually is zero except for $|i|< L,|j| < L$ where $L$ is small. Here $x$ is the input of some layer of your RNN, $y$ its output, and $h$ are the weights you are learning for this layer (so they are the weights between the neurons, but those weights are constrained such that the layer $l+1$ is obtained by convolution of the layer $l$ with the weights $h$)

Comment: Yes I am aware of what a convolution is, I just really would like an explanation to the question I asked specifically. What is the length, breadth and depth of the input volume

Comment: If you understand everything I wrote, then that's all, you know what is a convolutional layer (and how to implement the gradient descent / backpropagation for learning the weights of the filter)

Comment: Actually I'd really like to understand the language they use in the Wiki article. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Usually in the context of filters, "length" refers to the length of the filter : the $L$ I wrote (or possibly $L^2$ in 2d).

Comment: Honestly,  except this image that is quite clear : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Typical_cnn.png the wikipedia article is terrible and what is says looks completely useless, so find another source.

Comment: And remember that two convolutional (more generally linear) layers can always be reduced to only one convolutional/linear layer, so between two linear layers there is always a non-linear layer.

Comment: I have got a lot of valuable information out of the wiki article so I wouldn't like to dismiss it but I'd really like to understand the language it uses. I'm interested in how the size and depth of the input image effects the number of neurons and depth of each convolution layer.

Comment: It depends on the application. As usual in the context of ANN, you have to download a working source-code and see how it is made exactly.

Comment: Input volume refers to the 3D object consisting of a stack of 2D maps. Depth of the input volume will refer to the number of channels (2D maps) in that stack. For the input, this is the colour channels; pixel values for red, green and blue. After some convolutional layer has been applied, it becomes the number of filters at the previous layer, since each one produces its own feature map to compose the new stack.